# Tissue grafting in marine invertebrates

Tags: development, transplantation

I'm trying to source a procedure for a transplanting tissue in regenerating polyps. Would anyone happen to know where I can find a method of adhering to donor to host tissue?

Thanks

Comment: I think what @bonCodigo is trying to ask is what kind of polyps you are talking about (their habitat etc).

Comment: Colonial anthozoans located in the intertidal region. Truthfully, I can't find a procedure for grafting tissue in any aquatic invertebrate. I'm just looking for a good starting point.